# django rest framework - How to add post parameters to api document(drf_yasg)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

```
x_param = openapi.Parameter('x', in_=openapi.IN_FORM, description='srring',
                                   type=openapi.TYPE_STRING)

y_param = openapi.Parameter('y', in_=openapi.IN_FORM, description='string',
                                   type=openapi.TYPE_STRING)

@swagger_auto_schema(method='post', manual_parameters=[x_param,y_param])
@api_view(['POST'])
def test(request):
    pass
```

I used `drf_yasg` as a swagger.

I did the coding above and tested it with swagger, and when I checked with Chrome, the request payload is `x = 124 & y = 124124`.

And, with the following message, a bad request error occurred.

```
{
  "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
}
```

Is it wrong to add post parameters to the swagger?

Comment: The `in_=openapi.IN_FORM` tells it that you expect it to be a form, while your API is configured to accept JSON?

Comment: @SungHoKim based on the JSON response, the server seems to be looking for valid JSON data in the POST body. Did you try formatting your request body accordingly? Maybe like `{'x': 124, 'y': 124124}` ?

Comment: Try changing your `openapi.IN_FORM` to `openapi.IN_BODY`

Comment: So I just want tot point out that I switched from drf-yasg to drf-specacular and haven't looked back. It was way simpler at customizing and is actively maintained.The last commit on drf-yasg was 3 months ago... https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding parameters of type `form` to swagger, but your view seems to expect a json payload in the request body. In that case you probably want to use `request_body` with an `openapi.Schema` object.

```
@swagger_auto_schema(method='post', request_body=openapi.Schema(
    type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT, 
    properties={
        'x': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, description='string'),
        'y': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, description='string'),
    }
))
@api_view(['POST'])
def test(request):
    pass
```

This will automatically wrap your `Schema` into a `Parameter` of `in_=openapi.IN_BODY`.
See https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/openapi.html for details.

Of course, the preferred way would be to use a class-based `GenericAPIView` together with a `Serializer`, which would simplify both the view code and the doc introspection.

Comment: Of course, the preferred way would be to use a class-based GenericAPIView together with a Serializer : Is there a way to specify write / read serializer separately?

Comment: Same issue in classbased views, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63068565/drf-yasg-custom-json-body

Comment: This answer saved my time and fixed my issue